# Hadoop dev error ".gvfs does not exist"

Tags: hadoop

I'm picking up some hadoop dev skills and am facing an error '.gvfs does not exist'.

I ran [`bin/hadoop fs -ls file:///home`] and it gave me the result:
'Found 1 items
drwxr-xr-x    - gl gl         4096 2014-10-28 21:50 /home/gl'

However, when I ran [`bin/hadoop fs -ls file:///home/gl`], it throws the error:
'ls: could not get get listing for 'file:/home/gl' : File file:/home/gl/.gvfs does not exist.'

Am I missing something or is there a way to sidestep this error?

Update (response to Apesa):

- I'm running Linux on an Oracle VM VirtualBox Manager.
- I ran [`pwd`] and the result is '/home/gl'
- I ran [`ls -ltr`] and it lists out other directories like 'Videos', 'Templates', 'Pictures' etc.

Comment: Fill in some blanks such as what OS are you on and what dir have you formatted as HDFS. Also, look in File Manager or Terminal using ls -ltr in your home/gl/ dir to make sure it is missing. .gvfs is a FUSE mount point for file shares and programs and will regenerate itself.

Comment: Hi @apesa, I'm running Linux on an Oracle VM VirtualBox Manager.
I ran [pwd] and the result is '/home/gl'
I ran [ls -ltr] and it lists out other directories like 'Videos', 'Templates', 'Pictures' etc.

Answer (score 0):

It's a permission problem on some files that you need to list in some directory. 
For example, the .gvfs directory in your user directory can't be accessed outside a root environment. 
This is why it works inside some directories, but some don't work:

Try to list your directory using sudo:

```
sudo bin/hadoop fs -ls file:///home/gl
```

It should work, but be careful with sudo :)